# Downloading entire sites for offline viewing

Tags: downloading-website-files

I'd like to download a website to whiten it into a private network.

I know it's being done a lot with StackOverflow itself, I just don't know how to do it myself.

The specific site I want to download is [CPP-QUIZ](http://cppquiz.org/) with all the questions and explanations.

I've tried doing it with HTTrack, but it seems to download just a couple of questions and then it fails.

What is usually done to do something like this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a tool like [wget](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/) or [curl](http://curl.haxx.se/). If the site had an index then you could use wget's recursive option. It seems like it does not (the homepage just seems to choose a question at random for that specific site).

In that case you can just start generating commands:

```
wget http://cppquiz.org/quiz/question/1
wget http://cppquiz.org/quiz/question/2
wget http://cppquiz.org/quiz/question/3
```

And so on. After running those commands you would have the files downloaded to the directory you ran the commands from.

Answer (score 0):

I was also wondering the same thing & stumbled upon this Github project this week called Diskernet

- it saves resources to your file system as your browsing using your web browser (when launched with the diskernet binary or CLI tool)

It's still an early project, but I found I already started making use of it this week & it worked great!

- https://github.com/i5ik/Diskernet

Highlights:

- is able to download Single Page Web applications (doesn't use `wget`)
- once you download a site, it works offline

There are alternative tools like SiteSucker, but I found Diskernet to work even for websites that require authentication